# Concatenate more than two matrices - get out of memory error

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to concatenate some matrices (20-30). I wrote a simple function:

```
function [ appendedResults ] = appendResults( startNumber, endNumber  )

str2 = '_simulation.xlsx';
str1 = num2str(startNumber);
InputFilename = strcat(str1, str2);     

appendedResults =  uint16( xlsread(InputFilename ) );

for i= startNumber+1  :  endNumber
    temp_simulationResults = uint16( xlsread(InputFilename ) );
    appendedResults = vertcat( appendedResults, temp_simulationResults );
end

filename1 = strcat('appended',  str2);  
xlswrite(filename1, appendedResults);

end
```

It's works fine if I use 3-4 matrices. But when I'm using more, I get an error:

```
Error using xlswrite (line 219)
Error: Not enough memory
```

Then the matlab use 6 GigaByte (!!) memory. The matrices are only 7 MegaByte!

I wrote another function with for loops( without Matlab Vertcat function).
I get the same error!

```
function [ appendedResults ] = appendResultsInOneMatrix( startNumber, endNumber )

str2 = '__simulation.xlsx';
str1 = num2str(startNumber);
InputFilename = strcat(str1, str2);     

numberOfItems = (endNumber - startNumber) + 1 ;

firstResults =   uint16(  xlsread(InputFilename ) );
[row , col] = size(firstResults);

appendedResults =   zeros ( row * numberOfItems , col);

for i=1: row
    for j=1:col
        appendedResults( i , j ) = firstResults( i , j);
    end
end

for i= startNumber+1 : endNumber

    str1 = num2str(i);
    InputFilename = strcat(str1, str2);

    temp_simulationResults = uint16( xlsread(InputFilename ) );
    [temp_row , temp_col] = size(temp_simulationResults);

    for m = 1 : temp_row
           for n = 1 :  temp_col

               appendedResults( m+row , n ) = temp_simulationResults( m , n);
           end

    end

end


    filename1 = strcat('appended',  str2); 
    xlswrite(filename1, appendedResults);

end
```

What's wrong?

Comment: any news yet, have you understood my answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concatenate matrices, the resulting dimensions will be the maxima of the individual dimensions of the input matrices times the number of matrices; for example, if matrix `A` is 1x1,000,000 and matrix `B` is 1,000,000x1, the individual storage of these matrices would only be 1 million elements, but the resulting matrix would need to store 2* 10<sup>12</sup> elements!

**EDIT**: also, Excel files *definitely* are not the storage you should be using for tables with more than a million entries!

**EDIT2**: Take a piece of paper. Draw a 1cm x 10cm (width x height) rectangle on it, write "matrix A" on it so you know how the rectangle is oriented and don't accidentially rotate it. Cut it out. Draw a 10cm x 1cm rectange, write "matrix B" on it, for the same reason.

Concatenate both rectangles. What is the **area** of the rectangle you need to enclose this shape? What's the sum of areas of the "matrix A" and "matrix B" rectangles?

Matrices are rectangular, and by default you will have to have enough space to store the minimum rectangle that contains the concatenation of your matrices. You can change that by using sparse matrices in Matlab (that's a long topic, and can't be explained in a single StackOverflow answer), but that won't change the fact that what you're doing probably doesn't make the least sense.

Comment: Thanx the reply! Sorry, I don't understand why need 10^12 elements to store two matrices with 10^6 elements. What can I do? How to solve it?

Comment: All matrices are 35.000 x 57 (35000 rows and 57 columns), so when I concatenate two matrices then will be 70.000 x 57. If I concatenate three then 105000 x 57.

Comment: a) are you sure that's the case and b) that's simply too big for xlswrite, it needs more memory than just the values to write things to an excel file. Also, I can't imagine Excel dealing with a 105,000 x 57 table very well, so why do you store in that format? It's really not meant for that kind of data.

Comment: Yes, I threw out the excel to the trash and I'm using Matlab save function. It's works fine. Thank you!